# Ask about AppleScript keystrokes

Tags: macos, applescript

I have never used AppleScript before.
This is the first time I have to make a keystroke. I do not know what it is.
I would like to create a command that puts shift + f5, control + v, shift + f5, i, down, v, shift + i, please

Comment: please read the documentation on applescript and try to code something yourself first. when you have some code and are stuck, come back and ask for help

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this nice page (http://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes/) to get yourself started.

It'll be something like the code below. You might want to consider activating your app first as well as putting a delay between the key codes just in case.

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 96 using {shift down}
    key code 9 using {control down}
    key code 96 using {shift down}
    key code 34
    key code 125
    key code 9
    key code 34 using {shift down}
end tell
```